# Upgrade to OneSignal 4.0 SDK not compatible with PCL Profile44 and others Visual Studio Mac 2022

Tags: xamarin, nuget, visual-studio-2022, onesignal

when trying to install the OneSignal 4.x SDK to the shared project part of my pcs project I get the following error:

OneSignalSDK.Xamarin 4.1.0 with .NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile259.
Package OneSignalSDK.Xamarin 4.1.0 is not compatible with portable45-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile259). Package OneSignalSDK.Xamarin 4.1.0 supports:

- monoandroid41 (MonoAndroid,Version=v4.1)
- netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
- xamarinios (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v0.0)

I tried almost every other Profile with the same result. I cant get this to install.
The SDK installs fine in the iOS and Android projects. And the former sdk 3.x also installed fine.

Any help on this would be great!

Thanks
Thomas

Comment: you need to update your Xamarin Forms project to netstandard2.0

Comment: It is 2022, almost 2023 and people are still using PCL  Please at least migrate the project to netstandard2.0. Even consider a migration to net6.0.

Comment: @Cheesebaron - while I agree with the underlying suggestion, as written that could be considered "unkind". Its best to make a technical recommendation using "neutral" wording. Thanks.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Use the flag option and let it be up to the moderators to decide that. Regardless of your opinion on my comment. When someone is using 11 year old tech, which since has been replaced twice with newer stuff, that is hilarious.